# Ajax for laravel 4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to set up ajax for laravel, but it won't work.
I have controller for posting comments. javascript which blocks the submit button and sends ajax which is returning 500 error

```
public function postComment()
{
    if (Request::ajax()) 
    {
        return Response::json(['blah' => 'ohhh']);
        }
}

    $('#submit_comment').click(function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "http://page.dev/posts/comment",
        data : 
        {
            comment : $("#comment_area").text()
        }
    });

});

<script type="text/javascript">var comment = "{{URL::action('PostsController@postComment')}}"; </script>
```

What it returns is 500 internal server error

**UPD:**

```
    Route::get('posts/{id}', ['as' => 'post', 'uses' => 'PostsController@getShow'])->where('id', '\d+'); // Where id == number
Route::get('category/{id}', ['as' => 'category', 'uses' => 'PostsController@getCategory'])->where('id', '\d+');
```

**SOLUTION:**
   I used in constructor csrf protection. after i removed csrf protection from postComment it worked for me
    Route::controller('posts', 'PostsController');

Comment: Your 500 server response likely comes with an error message (hopefully). Can you search for that? Should be part of the response. Lastly, can you let us know what files that code is in? It looks like you're mixing in your controller code with your view code in the above code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to to offer advice without seeing your route, controller, view code neatly separated.  However, this is the bare minimum necessary to achieve your desired outcome:

In your routes.php

```
Route::post('/comment', function()
{
    return Response::json(['blah' => 'ohhh']);
});
```

In your view:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "comment",
});
```

if you are getting a 500 response then it is likely that you have a problem with your route to controller@postComment.

Comment: sorry for late response... using simple example as you showed with Route, it worked... but when I try to attach the same to controller it' showing me 500.

Comment: I've understood only that it works with Route::post('posts/comment', function(){});, but it won't work if I add ['uses' => 'PostsController@postComment']